# whoto rewrite specific conditions in htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Have webpage with search in: index.php?search=foo need redirect all text http://foo.com/findme to index.php?search=findme but not 404 real files.

Example of this:

```
http://foo.com/john => find john
http://foo.com/john+abc => find john abc
http://foo.com/john.jpg => set 404 (if not exist)
http://foo.com/john/foo.jpg => set 404 (if not exist)
http://foo.com/john/foo.php => set 404 (if not exist)
http://foo.com/john/ => set 404 (if not exist)
```

Other result find the query string in php.
Example: 11.111.111-1, 111111111, 22222.222-k, 11111111.1

Need black list in search by extension?

need all jpg, php, txt, xml, etc etc or directory (contain "/"), set 404 if not exist

Have this:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !(\/) <=== dont work
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?search=$1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /index.php?search=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks :). What is QSA?

Comment: `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.